# Allowing access to admin interface on production website

Tags: url, admin, production, amazon-elb

1. We are about to **GO-LIVE** with website (amazon **EC2** / **ELB** ) which contains **delicate user information.**
2. No matter the reason **WHY** We want to do this, our questions :

   A. will it be secured enough to allow **ADMIN** access via : 
   https://www.website.com/admin-path ? (using : robotos.txt / crednitals / restric ip to secure it  ).

   B. If the answer is yes, are there any **ELB instance rules** that can assist keeping this configuration secured.

Answer (score 0):

Our current solution is :

- **Amazon side**

  - We are working with Amazon ELB  ( Load Balancer ), thus :
  - Opening specific HTTP port (e.g. 8080) in ELB.
  - Configuring security group to allow access on this URL:port only for our 
    **specific IP**
- **Our Application side**

  - Url is not searchable (robots etc).
  - Url can be accessed with credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you are using a VPC for your back-end instances you can apply [security groups to your ELB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-security-groups.html). Just like EC2 security groups these will restrict ALL access based on IP address.

If you're using [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) in front of your ELB to provide CDN services to your site then you can make use of Amazon's recently announced [Web Application Firewall (WAF)](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) to provide more fine-grained access. With WAF you could, for example, restrict access to /admin-path to a specific IP address or range of addresses. You could also restrict access based on other HTTP headers, so you could only allow access if certain cookies exist, if a specific browser (via the User Agent string) is used, if there's a referral from your own domain, etc.

About the only other option you have is to roll your own security.  We front our application with Apache, and we have rules in place that restrict access to admin URL's on a number of levels.  HTTP Auth passwords are required, access must be from a defined set of IP's, etc.  Doing all this from within Apache (or pretty much any web server) is relatively straightforward.